# Perl/Gtk3, add a background image to a window

Tags: css, perl, gtk3

I'm trying to add a background image to a window. Using CSS styles, it's simple enough, but I only want to add the image to a single window, not all of them.

The script below creates two Gtk windows, one with CSS, the other without. It doesn't work because the CSS style is added to both windows.

I would be happy to add a background image to a Gtk3::Frame, or a Gtk3::Box, or even to avoid CSS altogether, but I can't get any of these methods to work.

I think the code is *almost* right, because it *does* work for adding a background image to just one Gtk3::TextView (but not both of them).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package bgtest;

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;

use Gtk3 '-init';
use Glib qw(TRUE FALSE);
use Cairo;

&drawWin(FALSE);
&drawWin(TRUE);

Gtk3->main();

sub drawWin {

    my ($cssFlag) = @_;

    my $window = Gtk3::Window->new('toplevel');
    $window->set_position('center');
    $window->set_default_size(400, 300);
    $window->signal_connect('delete-event' => sub {

        Gtk3->main_quit();
        exit;
    });

    if ($cssFlag) {

        # Set up the window's background image using a CSS style
        $window->set_title('CSS ON');

        my $imagePath = "/home/YOURNAME/bg.png";

        my $provider = Gtk3::CssProvider->new();
        my $display = Gtk3::Gdk::Display::get_default();
        my $screen = Gtk3::Gdk::Display::get_default_screen($display);
        Gtk3::StyleContext::add_provider_for_screen($screen, $provider, 600);

        my $theming = "#my_win_id, window.background {\n";
        $theming .= "   background-image: url(\"$imagePath\");\n";
        $theming .= "   background-repeat: repeat;\n";
        $theming .= "   background-position: top left;\n";
        $theming .= "}";

        $provider->load_from_data ([map ord, split //, $theming]);

        my $context = $window->get_style_context();
        $context->add_provider($provider, 600);

    } else {

        # Don't use a background image
        $window->set_title('CSS OFF');
    }

    $window->show_all();

    return $window;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to add a background image to a window. Using CSS styles,
>   it's simple enough, but I only want to add the image to a single
>   window, not all of them.

Just remove the screen provider (and keep the window provider). So comment out the line:

```
Gtk3::StyleContext::add_provider_for_screen($screen, $provider, 600);
```

Comment: Thanks Håkon, you're the best!